# About properties of groupoid C*-algebras 

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, reference-request, groupoids

I'm interested in the following kind of questions about groupoid $C^*$-algebras.

1) If $G_1 \times_{H} \ G_2$ is a fibre product of (nice) groupoids do we have something like $$C^\star(G_1 \times_{H} \ G_2) \cong C^*(G_1) \otimes_{C^\star(H)} C^*(G_2) ?$$
2) Of course, in general, there is an ambiguity about the above tensor product. So what is a good notion of amenability for groupoids? (In the sense that the groupoid $C^*$ algebra of an amenable groupoid is nuclear.)

Apart from Renault's classic about groupoid $C^*$-algebras I do not really know any other reference for this subject.

Thanks!

Comment: Amenability of groupoids and nuclearity of their $C^*$ algebras is discussed in Section 5.6 of N. Brown, and N. Ozawa: "$C^*$-algebras and finite-dimensional approximations" (http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2391387).  They also give a number of references at the end of the chapter.

Comment: thank you very much for bringing this book to my attention!

Answer (score 2):

I'll post this, although you probably already know about it:

C. Anantharaman-Delaroche et J. Renault, *Amenable groupoids* (avec un appendice
par E. Germain), Monographie de l'Enseignement Mathématique (Genève), 36,
2000.

I hope this is helpful. Note: I'm not claiming that the amenability discussed here is the sort that you need. I only answer since you claim to know no reference for amenability of groupoids.